# What standardized formats (if any) exist for boolean circuits?

Tags: circuits

Being able to represent a Boolean circuit is useful in a number of areas of Computer Science, such as Circuit Satisfiability, Zero-Knowledge Proofs and Garbled Circuits.

Are there any standards for how such a circuit should be represented in a text file?
By a standard I mean very specific instructions about how wires should be labeled, how gates should be denoted and how any metadata (e.g. total number of gates) should be stored. In other words, an API which would allow different programs that used circuits as inputs/outputs to communicate with each other directly. For instance, say you were building a circuit optimizer that you wanted to be usable by all the applications I mentioned above. What format should you use?

I searched for RFCs but didn't find any (https://tools.ietf.org/).

(Feel free to migrate this question to another SE site if appropriate.)